# Minor confusion on using PC features for classification

Tags: machine-learning, pca, normalization

I have what I believe to be a simple question. I have also browsed some of the PCA related materials here.

I have an unlabeled $M$ by $N$ data matrix, consisting of $M=1000$ points, and $N=500$ features. I standardize my matrix, perform PCA, and decide to use the top two PC's. Let us assume that those turn out to be fantastic features to use, and I decide to run a (k=3)-means, get my nice decision space, etc, all is good in the world.

**The question:** When I have a new data point that I want to classify as belonging to one of those three clusters:

- It seems to be that I have to always retain the first two columns of my $U$ matrix that I used in the PCA, forever, so that I can always project my new point unto them. Is this correct?
- When I did PCA, I had to standardize my data, that is, remove the mean of the features, and make their std's unity. So, isnt there something I should also do to this new data point now that I have it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `run a (k=3)-means`? Is that smth about k-means clustering? Did you do the clustering on only those 2 PCs? Why they were fantastic, why just k=3, how did your classification decision rule come and why do you think world is good with all that?

Comment: @ttnphns Oh, I just mean let us say I run a k-means clustering, with k=3, for this example. Yes, clustering on only those two pcs, again, as an example. I am just making up numbers, what I am trying to ascertain really is insight into the two bullets on there - that is, given a new point, how do I go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Correct.
- You should handle the new input in the same way, so you need to remember the means and stds and apply the same normalization procedure. To put it differently, PCA does a basis transformation, you have to make sure that you start from the same basis so if you scaled/translated/transformed it in some way, you should apply that same scaling/translation/transformation before applying PCA again.

Comment: Ah ok, right, it just strikes me as... 'unsafe', to always use the same 2 columns of the U matrix forever?... I just wanted to make sure that was ok.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by unsafe ...

Comment: What I mean is that, maintaining the std vector, mean vector, and the necessary columns of $U$ are then standard practice in a case like this, where you want to use pcs as your features, and as an input into a machine learning algorithm?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you always respect the separation between train/(validation)/test sets, so don't calculate the mean/stdvs/PCA on any data included in the (validation)/test set.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the subtracting of the means and dividing by the standard deviation, you need to use the covariance matrix. It is called data whitening and is done as $\Sigma^(\frac{-1}{2})(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})$

Comment: Hmm I dont think I am whitening the data, that would imply all the eigenvalues are the same. I do think that I am diagonalizing it though. (ie, making the covariance matrix diagonal).

Comment: I am thinking of whitening the projections